# get a message information in create_task() without using async function

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

so, im trying to send a discord message without using the async function and it works, but theres an problem, i cant get information about the message (like message ID).

This is my code:

```
import thread, discord
channel = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] #assume this is channel id

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def notification():
    def template(latest_data):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ring Ring!", description=latest_data["des"], colour=discord.Colour.green())
        return embed

    def send(none,divided_channels,page):
        for channel_id in divided_channels:
            message_info = client.loop.create_task(channel.send(embed=page))
            # i want to get the message id i sent in in message_info

    def newnotification(page):
        split = 5
        looping = 0
        while looping < len(channel):
            divided_channels = channel[looping:(split+looping)]
            looping += split
            var_name = f"variable{looping}"
            globals()[var_name] = threading.Thread(target=send,args=(divided_channels,divided_channels,page))
            globals()[var_name].start()

global oldest_data, channel
latest_data = file("notification.json")
if (oldest_data != latest_data):
    page = template(latest_data)
    newnotification(page)
else:
    oldnotification()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    notification.start()
```

ive tried using result and .result() but it didnt work. if i use **message_info.result**, i will get: connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000018743206550>, and if i use **message_info.result()**, i get: asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Result is not set.

Comment: Why not use the [discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) with the [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library? Rather than using `discord.py` which is async.

Answer (score 0):

`loop.create_task` creates and returns a task, not any kind of message info (the name is a big hint). If you want the value returned by the `channel.send()` function you'll need to `await` the task and give it a chance to run:

```py
def send(none,divided_channels,page):
    for channel_id in divided_channels:
        message_info = await client.loop.create_task(channel.send(embed=page))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables